# dynamically created Bootstrap Modal gets wrong height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a modal after an JQuery ajax call and filling it with a template, but the modal gets no height. Only if i add height manually in the show.bs.modal event i get the result i want.

```
$('span[data-toggle="filemanager"]').click(function( event ) {

  $('#modal-filemanager').remove();

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url("filemanager/view")?>",
    dataType: 'html' })
    .done(function(data) {
      $('body').append('<div id="modal-filemanager" class="modal">' + data + '</div>');
      /* only with this code i get height on my modal */
      $('#modal-filemanager').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
          height: ($( window ).height()*0.7)
       });
      });
      /* */
      $('#modal-filemanager').modal('show');          
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

And the template:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Filemanager</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div row="row">
    <?php if(isset($directories)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($directories as $directory) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?php echo site_url("filemanager/load").'?path='.$path.'/'.$directory->name; ?>" class="directory"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-5x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label>Folder Name
            <?php //echo $directory->name; ?>
            </label>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And screenshots first shows my problem and the second shows the result after adding css :

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to share the CSS.

Comment: thank you for your interest. well i have no custom css for the modal. it's just the default of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant believe that my problem was a syntax error. I had `div row="row"` rather than `class="row"`. Anyway thanks for the help.